# ReactJS Multiple Input problem setState and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Hi guys i need help how to make the editchange will not go through all the input and make changes to it.

When i typed an input inside one of the textbox it repeats to other inputs. Im new to react so i having trouble dealing with this.

the map is on loop,[image] for example it displays three from api and 3 inputs will appear.

See the picture, hope you can help me.

```
handleSubmitReply(event, discussionid, classid){
        event.preventDefault();
        let userid = sessionStorage.getItem('userid');
        const {
            userAccountId,
            reply
        } = this.state;

        const postData = {
            userAccountId:userid,
            reply
        };
        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");

        fetch('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Class/'+ classid +'/discussion/'+discussionid+'/response', {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(postData),
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status === 400){
            return response.json();
            }else{
            this.addNotification('success', 'Success', 'All Data is Saved', 'top-right')
            this.componentDidMount();
            return response.json();
            }
        })
        .then(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData);
            return responseData;
        })
        .catch(err => {

            console.log("fetch error" + err);
        });

    }
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

handleChange(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(event.target.name)
                console.log(event.target.value)
                this.setState({
                    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                });
            };


{discussionData.map(dd => (
  <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light" placeholder="Reply" name={dd.discussion.instructions} value={this.state[dd.discussion.instructions]} onChange={this.handleChange} />
))}
```

here is the updated code, what will i do to the postData "reply" when i submit it. it requires to fill all the fields.

How to serialize it to be posted in my API

Comment: You need to set unique name to your inputs so that their state can be managed separately.

Comment: All of your inputs have `name="reply"`, so `event.target.name` will always be `"reply"`, s that's all you'll ever set in state. You'll need to give both the `input`s and the state properties unique names based on `item`. You haven't shown us what `items` contains, so it's hard to be more specific, but for instance if each `item` had a `name` property, you'd use `name={item.name} value={this.state[item.name]}` and then your `handleChange` would update it correctly.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder i updated my code your suggestion works. I have another problem after  its in the post thanks

Answer (score 1):

`event.target.name` will always be `"reply"` as every one of your inputs has `name="reply"`.

Giving every input a unique name should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like that

```
handleChange(event, i) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(event.target.name)
                console.log(event.target.value)
                this.setState({
                    [`${event.target.name}{index}`]: event.target.value
                });
            };


{items.map((item, index)=> (
  <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light" placeholder="Reply" name=`name${index}` value= 
  {this.state.reply} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)} />
))}
```

And create initial state as an array. May be this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bhatti i did this name={item.name} value={this.state[item.name]}. Im on POST data now. What will be the postData to serialize the input? this is my data postData = {
            userAccountId:userid,
            reply
        }; reply part

Comment: this.state should have all the values. Just console.log(this.state) and analyse data and see what you want and send it in a post request. Something like that {reply: JSON.stringify(this.state)}